# Passing credentials to a standalone RCP based application through .bat file

Tags: eclipse, batch-file, rcp

I have an Eclipse RCP based application It starts with a splash screen, which has Host, Username, Password as fields and a button for authenticating those credentials.

My project requirement is automating this procedure. I created a .bat file , in which I wrote a script to open that application and bypassed the splash screen by "-nosplash" command.

Is there any way in which I can pass these credentials and automate this procedure through a .bat file or some other means?

-nosplash was in eclipse help documentation

Comment: Is this an RCP that you have written or is it an existing RCP from someone else?

Comment: I am working in a product , which is developed inEclipse RCP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```java
String [] args = Platform.getApplicationArgs();
```

to get the arguments to your RCP. So if you specify the host, user and password as arguments to the rcp command in the .bat file you can use this to process them in the RCP.

So your .bat file might contain:

```
yourrcpapp -host host -user user -password password
```

And your RCP code would loop through the `args` picking out these values

Comment: Where to use this code ? In RCP ? But i want to pass the credentials from the .bat file ? Is that possible

Comment: Yes this code goes in your RCP. Added more detail to the answer

Comment: But , is there any way , by which i can pass the credentials in the .bat file , so on the start up , these values get passed to the fields on the Splash screen of the RCP application or through some other means .....

Comment: You just have to use Platform.getApplicationArgs in the splash screen code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help . Will try it and update the status of it :)